# Sublime Video Player Will not Work on Customized WP Theme in IE9/IE10

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internet-explorer, video

Okay,

I have recently uploaded mp4s to a customized WP theme with as many as twenty videos.
The thing is only a half of the videos will not work in IE 9 and IE 10 (Win 7 and Win 8). Getting "media source loading failed" error. All videos work fine on mobile formats as well as in Chrome/Safari/FireFox browser (all except IE, I know, hold back your shock folks). Changing the .htaccess file to work with ogg webm files does not work, it simply breaks the site.

I have visited the Sublime Video Site and used Handbrake (a compressor) per their (Sublime Video's)https://getsatisfaction.com/sublimevideo/topics/yet_another_ie9_challenge?utm_content=reply_link&utm_medium=email&utm_source=reply_notification. No Help.

I am using Final Cut Compressor 4, and I must admit, I am new at compressing files for the web. After multiple posts on Sublime Video site, I have little to no response from their forum. I do know that their own player does not work in IE 10, even using their own video on their own site (http://test.sublimevideo.net/responsive-layout).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my site
(http://www.mannachurch.org/online-sermons/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue does seem be to change the MIME in Amazon S3.

To be more specific, you need to log into Amazon S3 Console

- right click on the file you need to change
- click on properties
- click on metadata
- HIGHLIGHT the text in "value" category (cause "video/mp4" will not be in the drop down)
- manually type in "video/mp4"
- hit save

Working on all browsers now.